# Same value popped regardless of pushed values in a stack

Tags: c, stack

I am writing a simple stack program (the main function just determines what the user is asking you to do).

However, it has "a bug", where it just continues to "pop" the same value off (It's not actually popping anything off).

Am I using structures and pointers incorrectly? Or is it a not-so-obvious coding mistake?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} first;

void push(int);
void pop();

int main(void)
{
    int command = 0;
    
    while (command != 3)
    {
        printf("Enter your choice:\n1) Push integer\n2) Pop Integer\n3) Quit.\n");
        scanf("%d",&command);
        if (command == 1)
        {
            // push
            int num;
            scanf("%d",&num);
            push(num);
        }
        else
        {
            if (command == 2)
            {
                pop();
            }
            else
            {
                if (command != 3)
                {
                    printf("Command not understood.\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void push (int x)
{
    struct node newNode;
    newNode.data = x;
    newNode.prev = NULL;
    newNode.next = &first;
    first = newNode;
    printf("%d was pushed onto the stack.\n", first.data);
}

void pop()
{
    if (first.data == '\0')
    {
        printf("Error: Stack Empty.\n");
        return; 
    }
    printf("%d was popped off the stack.\n", first.data);
    first = *(first.next);
    first.prev = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `first` is a single global `node`, and it's the only `node` you ever have (aside from a temporary local `node` inside your call to `push`).

This line:

```c
first = newNode;
```

just copies the contents of `newNode` over into `first`; and since `newNode.next` is pointing to `first`, this means that now `first.next` is pointing to `first`, so you have a single-element circular linked list.

Similarly, this line:

```c
first = *(first.next);
```

just copies the contents of `*(first.next)` over into `first`; which is a no-op, since (due to the above), `*(first.next)` *is* `first`.

To solve this problem, you actually need to dynamically create nodes, using `malloc` (and `free`). And your global `first` variable should be a pointer — a `node *` — that always points to the top element of the stack. (Better yet, your `push` and `pop` functions should take `first` as an argument, rather than having this as a global variable. There's no need for these functions to only allow a single stack to exist.)

Answer (score 5):

1. `first` should be a pointer. Change it to `struct node *first`;
2. in main, initialize `first = NULL`;
3. change your push/pop operations as below:

```c
void push (int x)
{
    struct node *newNode;// It should be a pointer
    newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = x;
    //newNode.prev = NULL; // You don't need this
    newNode->next = first;
    first = newNode;
    printf("%d was pushed onto the stack.\n", first->data);
}

void pop()
{
    struct node *prevPtr;
    //if (first.data == '\0')
    if (first == NULL) // check if stack is empty
    {
        printf("Error: Stack Empty.\n");
        return; 
    }

    printf("%d was popped off the stack.\n", first->data);
    prevPtr = first;
    first = first->next;

    free(prevPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's the value of `&first`?  Hint, it's always the same since `first` is statically allocated.  Even if you change the contents of the structure, the address won't change.  This might tell you why there's a bug in `push`.  You'll need to use `malloc` and `free` if you are going to have a structure of varying size.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to manage memory yourself, as C requires you to do, you need to know the difference between areas of memory known as the stack and the heap. (This "stack" is slightly different from the data structure you are creating in your program.)

Your `push()` function is creating a new node on the stack; when the function exits, the stack is popped and the memory occupied by your new node is up for grabs. The fact that you see values you entered is due to the fact that your program is very simple. If it was calling other functions that did other things they would almost certainly overwrite that part of the stack and when you called `pop()`, you would see garbage.

As others have indicated, you need to use the functions `malloc()` and `free()`, which give you memory from the heap instead of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a stack with a linked list, make `first` variable as a pointer. Then, when you push a new node to the stack, make a new node by allocating on the heap memory using `malloc()`. That is if you intend to use it to point to the top of the stack.

In your code, `first` variable is overwritten by a new node since it is not a pointer variable, but a value variable. That results in the loss of the top node of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
void pop()
{
    struct node *prevPtr;
    //if (first.data == '\0')
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Stack Empty.\n");
        return; 
    }

    printf("%d was popped off the stack.\n", first->data);
    prevPtr = first;
    first = first->next;

    free(prevPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
  int size;
  int top;
  int *arr;
};

int isEmpty(struct stack* ptr){
    if(ptr->top == -1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
         return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct stack* ptr){
    if(ptr->top == ptr->size-1){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
         return 0;
    }
}

int display(struct stack *s){
    for(int i = s->top; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%d\n", s->arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct stack *s = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    s->size = 80;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int *)malloc(s->size * sizeof(int));
    
    s->top ++;
    s->arr[s->top] = 1;
    s->top ++;
    s->arr[s->top] = 2;
    s->top ++;
    s->arr[s->top] = 3;
    
    display(s);
    // if(isEmpty(s)){
    //     printf("Stack Empty!");
    // }
    // else{
    //     printf("Stack not empty!");
    // }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```c
#include<stdio.h>

#define max 10

int stack[max],top=-1,size=0;

void push()
{
    if(top==(max-1))
    {
        printf("stack full\n");
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        printf("enter the value which you want to insert\n");
        scanf("%d",&stack[top]);
    }
}

void pop()
{
    int str;

    if(top==-1)
    {
        printf("stack empty\n");
    }
    else
    {
        str=stack[top];
        top--;
        printf("the removed element is %d\n",str);
    }
}

void display()
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<top;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",stack[i]);
    }
}

void main()
{ 
    int enter,x;
    do
    {
        printf("enter 1 for push the element in the array\n");
        printf("enter 2 for pop the element in the array\n");
        printf("enter 3 for display the element in the array\n");
        scanf("%d",&enter);

        switch(enter)
        {
            case 1:push();
                break;
            case 2:pop();
                break;
            case 3:display();
                break;
            default:
                printf("invalid syntax");
        }
        printf("for continue press 0\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
    }
    while(x==0);
}
```